# Multiprocessing unable to automatically recycle zombie children processes for my on-the-fly data augmentation code

Tags: python-multiprocessing, data-augmentation

System info:

```
Linux Ubuntu
Docker
Python 3.6.8
```

I am doing on-the-fly data augmentation for medical image segmentation. Inspired by `line 158~161` of [faustomilletari/VNet](https://github.com/faustomilletari/VNet/blob/master/VNet.py), the code example for data augmentation is as below:

```
trainQueue = Queue(queue_size) # store patches
tr_dataPrep = [None] * nProc
for proc in range(nProc):
    tr_dataPrep[proc] = Process(target=data_aug_function, args=(train_files, trainQueue, patch_size))
    tr_dataPrep[proc].daemon = True
    tr_dataPrep[proc].start()
```

The code above was running well on one server, which is now not available, but failed on another server, where lots of zombie children processes came out after a while and the training process just hang there indefinitely.

It seems that some children processes were killed by the system but we don't know why.